I'm trying to convert 31-05-24 into May 31, 2024
I'm trying to convert 31-05-24 into May 31, 2024 using Format or FormatDate the best i can get is 31-05-24 -- i've even had success with converting 31-may-23 do I need to ask the client for a correction in the value to 05-31-24 for this to work?
SET @Date = FormatDate(@OPT2, "MM-dd-yy")
SET @FormattedDate = Format(@Date, "MMMM d, yyyy", "Date", "en-CA")


I'd explore incorporating some validation into the string that is passed in case client changes their mind without warning, but the easy option is to break string apart.
%%[
SET @OPT2           = "31-05-24"
SET @dayPassed      = Substring(@OPT2,1,2)
SET @monthPassed    = Substring(@OPT2,4,2)
SET @yearPassed     = Substring(@OPT2,7,2)
SET @fullDatePassed = Concat(@monthPassed,"/",@dayPassed,"/",@yearPassed)
SET @OPT2_STD       = StringToDate(@fullDatePassed)
SET @FormattedDate  = Format(@OPT2_STD, "MMMM d, yyyy","","en-CA")
]%%

FormattedDate: %%=v(@FormattedDate)=%%
^Output --> FormattedDate: May 31, 2024

Thank you Eduardo Arias, this worked perfectly!

You can try to convert the string to date first, then format it.
%%[
    set @date = '31-05-24'
    set @date = StringToDate(@date)
    set @formatedDate = Format(@date, 'MMM dd, yyyy', 'Date')
]%%
%%=v(@formatedDate)=%%

Result: May 31, 2024
I believe the day should be 31 not 5.

Thank you, I have edited the post - let me try your suggestion

It doesn't work, thanks for suggesting, I think the issue is still the order of the numbers, it might work in the UK but in NA I think the order matters:
•An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a StringToDate function call. See inner exception for details.
•String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I am not sure how you altered your code but pretty sure it works. At least, I tested from my end.

Different ORGs have a different order of days to months to year so for me your solution doesn't work it has to be month before day.
